# Invalid Client with Oauth trying to access BigQuery

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-oauth

I created a small Bigquery project and now I need to access it via simple client-side javascript using an OAuth 2 flow.

Now I'm just running tests from my pc in Aptana, so when I was requesting my Client Id I specified the url `http://localhost:8020` in the field "javascript origins". 
I chose "web application" when asked what type of app I was registering.

I copy-pasted the example shown here:

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#client-side-javascript

and replaced  the project number and client id with my own ones, as told.
However, gapi.auth() fails and I get a popup window that says there's an error, namely "Invalid client". The other parameters are:

```
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
response_type=token
redirect_uri=postmessage
proxy=oauth2relay1213926397
origin=http://127.0.0.1:8020
state=1100863975|0.29982968120843295
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
```

I triple checked if the client ID and project number are correct, and they are (at least,they're identical to the ones  in my console).  My client id seems to be non-existant, though. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JavaScript origin to "`http://localhost`"

Comment: Done. Despite I can see the new value `http://localhost` in the console I still get the old value with the port number in the response. I guess that someway this change in the Client Id hasn't been stored, I'll try again later. Thanks for your help, if it doesn't work in an hour or two I'll come back.

Comment: Here I am, I tried this morning. I got again the Invalid client error and I didn't get 127.0.0.1 as origin. I think I'll write to somebody in Google and ask to check the specific project.

Comment: Just to triple-check your client ID, try going to https://code.google.com/apis/console, switch to the "API Access" panel, and find the section that says "Client ID for web applications".  (If there is no such section, click "Create another client ID".)  Then copy the exact client ID that you see in that panel (e.g., "123456789.apps.googleusercontent.com") into your code.  Also, make sure to list the exact origin mentioned in the error code (e.g., "http://127.0.0.1:8082") as a valid JavaScript origin.

Comment: Hi jcondit,what puzzles me is  the fact that, even if I've updated the value in the API console to `http//:localhost` as Michael suggested, I still get the old value for the origin.
The origin in the error trail you see is in fact just my previous origin address. That didn't work, so I came here and asked for help.
Yet I changed the origin as you suggested for checking again. It didn't work.

As for the triple checking, I've copy-pasted the project and client Ids right from the API access console, so it seems the problem is laying in the origin definition :(

Comment: PS: when I wrote "project id" I meant actually the project number ;)